# Not able to log off user sessions in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro, sas-metadata

In SAS Customer Intelligence, there are user sessions under Administration tab as shown below. The problem is there are few sessions of previous day which are not getting logged of.

To let you know I've already cleared all Unxsrv sessions by killing the PIDs but these sessions are still there.

I know it can be done by restarting SASServer 6_1 but restarting the server is not a solution.

Can any one let me know where can i find these PIDs and how to kill/logoff them.

[image]

Comment: It's commercial software, and I work for the company that sells it (disclaimer disclaimer) but here's how you do it with ESM:  https://vimeo.com/293611892